# Algorithm involving figuring out 10 digit number puzzle

Tags: java, algorithm

To determine if a number is divisible by 7, take the last digit off the number, double it and subtract the doubled number from the remaining number. If the result is evenly divisible by 7 (e.g. 14, 7, 0, -7, etc.), then the number is divisible by seven. This may need to be repeated several times.
Example: Is 3101 evenly divisible by 7?

```
 310   - take off the last digit of the number which was 1
  -2   - double the removed digit and subtract it
 308   - repeat the process by taking off the 8
-16    - and doubling it to get 16 which is subtracted
 14    - the result is 14 which is a multiple of 7
```

The following is the code that I did to get the number:

```
    for(int O =0; O <= 9 ; O++) {
            String a = String.valueOf(number[0]);
            String b = String.valueOf(number[1]);
            String c = String.valueOf(number[2]);
            String d = String.valueOf(number[3]);
            String e = String.valueOf(number[4]);
            String f = String.valueOf(number[5]);

            String h = a+b+c+d+e+f;
            int abcdef = Integer.valueOf(h);
            if ( (abcdef -(2*O) % 7) ==0 )
                number [6] = O;

    }
```

However, it is not giving me a number of such kind.I was able to get a number up until 6 where up until each digit the number is divisible by the respective index(if I start with 1, not 0 for the index).Which means index 1 is divisible by 1, index 2 is divisible by 2, index 3 is divisible by 3,......index 7 is divisible by 7.I want to form a number of such kind.Note that I could have done it without using the algorithm by the following way:

```
     for(int O =0; O <= 9 ; O++) {
        String a = String.valueOf(number[0]);
        String b = String.valueOf(number[1]);
        String c = String.valueOf(number[2]);
        String d = String.valueOf(number[3]);
        String e = String.valueOf(number[4]);
        String f = String.valueOf(number[5]);
        String g = String.valueOf(O);
        String h = a+b+c+d+e+f+g;
        int abcdefg = Integer.valueOf(h);
        if ( (abcdefg % 7) ==0 )
            number [6] = O;

}
```

However, I really want to do it using the algorithm that I described in the beginning.

Comment: Is this an assignment where it has to be this way, because there is a much easier way to check.

Comment: This is me myself playing around :)

Comment: Can you explain what the code snippets are supposed to do?

Comment: number[0] through number [5] form a number such that first digit divisible by 1,first two digits form a number divisible by 2, first 3 digits form a number divisible by 3.....

Comment: what happens when its not divisble by 7? You need a backup plan or you'll likely end up with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example calling code**:

```
int [] num = new int [7];
for (int i = 1000000; i < 9999999; i++)
{
    // put i into the array and check it
    if (checkDigitsDivisible(i, num))
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Check if a number has the first digit evenly divisible by 1, first 2 digits evenly divisible by 2, first 3 digits divisible by 3, etc.

```
public static boolean checkDigitsDivisible (int num, int [] arr)
{
    int one = num / 1000000;
    int two = num / 100000;
    int three = num / 10000;
    int four = num / 1000;
    int five = num / 100;
    int six = num / 10;
    int seven = num;

    arr[0] = one % 10;
    arr[1] = two % 10;
    arr[2] = three % 10;
    arr[3] = four % 10;
    arr[4] = five % 10;
    arr[5] = six % 10;
    arr[6] = seven % 10;

    return (one % 1 == 0) && 
           (two % 2 == 0) && 
           (three % 3 == 0) && 
           (four % 4 == 0) && 
           (five % 5 == 0) && 
           (six % 6 == 0) &&
           (isDivisibleBy7(seven));
}
```

A recursive solution to check if a number is divisible by 7 (algorithm as described in the question):

```
public static boolean isDivisibleBy7 (int n)
{       
    n = Math.abs(n);

    if (n == 0 || n == 7 || n == 14)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        int lastDigit = n % 10;
        int lastDigitOff = n / 10;

        int remainder = lastDigitOff - (lastDigit * 2);

        remainder = Math.abs(remainder);

        if (remainder > n)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return isDivisibleBy7(remainder);
    }
}
```

Comment: however, instead of boolean, I want to return a number that's in the 6th index of an array  of number that forms a number such that  first digit divisible by 1,first two digits form a number divisible by 2, first 3 digits form a number divisible by 3,first 4 digits form a number divisible by 4,first 5 digits form a number divisible by 5,first 6 digits form a number divisible by 6,first 7 digits form a number divisible by 7.

Comment: That's a whole separate problem. I would post that as another question along with the code you have tried so far. I can take a look at that question as well.

Comment: I explained this at the bottom of the question.My intention is to get the 6th index using the algorithm that I stated but it also has to meet the restrictions that I explained in the bottom.Sorry for the confusion.